# What version of the Google App Engine SDK do I have?

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I find out what version of the Google App Engine SDK I'm running?

I've looked under `dev_appserver.py` and `appcfg.py` and neither seem to be forthcoming with their version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least the linux SDK includes a file named `VERSION` in the SDK directory, which includes the version number as `release`. This is the file content for the `1.9.40` version:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/google_appengine_1.9.40
$ cat VERSION 
release: "1.9.40"
timestamp: 1465499889
api_versions: ['1']
supported_api_versions:
  python:
    api_versions: ['1']
  python27:
    api_versions: ['1']
  go:
    api_versions: ['go1']
  java7:
    api_versions: ['1.0']
```

UPDATE:

At least in the more recent SDK versions the version is also displayed in the top right corner of the development server's Admin page. The url of the Admin's page is displayed in the server's log at startup:

> INFO     2018-07-05 09:28:25,959 admin_server.py:152] Starting admin
>   server at: http://localhost:8000

Comment: Same on OSX. Thanks!

Comment: how can I know GAE SDK version from console? Actually I migrated my app engine backend(java) to endpoint framework 2.0 , at the same time I updated my GAE SDK version to latest version also, but still while deploying project using android studio IDE, its shows There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.9.64
Timestamp: Wed May 30 00:12:58 IST 2018
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.9.42.

Comment: You're definitely not at latest, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes :) Download the GAE SDK from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes

as I searching for the value of `appengine.sdk.version` 
As of today(07/05/2020), it is:

```
<appengine.sdk.version>1.9.80</appengine.sdk.version>
```